# After modifying a Bitmap, how can I modify the "modified" Bitmap and so on?

Tags: java, android, image, button, bitmap

Suppose I capture an image called `_originalBitmap`

1. Then I modify apply some type of `Brightness Increase` Filter to the `_originalBitmap` by

   `filteredBitmap = _BrightnessIncrease.filterImage(_originalBitmap);`
2. Then I click `Apply` button which saves the the `filteredBitmap` to a memory location.
3. I want to apply `Brightness Increase` **again** but on the `filteredBitmap`. Does anyone know how I can do that??????

**The code so far -
BrightnessIncrease Button:**

```
Button filter6Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter6_button);
    filter6Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            for (int i = MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE; i <= MainActivity.RIGHT_IMAGE; i++) {

                _filteredBitmaps[i] = _BrightnessIncrease
                        .filterImage(_originalBitmaps[i]);
                // */
            }
            _filterImageView
                    .setImageBitmap(_filteredBitmaps[MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you use 'copy on write': Copy the original bitmap to the filtered bitmap (array) when the user selects an operation for the first time on this image. After that, only operate on the filtered bitmaps (all your filters use the filtered images).
Then applying the filter twice would copy the image the first time, then apply the filter and the second time, just apply it again on the modified image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you save the filtered bitmaps in another list ?

```
for (int i = MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE; i <= MainActivity.RIGHT_IMAGE; i++) {
    _filterImageView[i] = _originalBitmaps[i].copy(_originalBitmaps[i].getConfig(), true);
} 
    Button filter6Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter6_button);
    filter6Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            for (int i = MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE; i <= MainActivity.RIGHT_IMAGE; i++) {

                _filterImageView[i] = _BrightnessIncrease
                        .filterImage(_filterImageView[i]);
                // */
            }
            _filterImageView
                    .setImageBitmap(_filterImageView[MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 for attempting it. However it doesnt seem to work, I tried 

for (int i = MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE; i <= MainActivity.RIGHT_IMAGE; i++) {

  _bitmaps[i].copy(_originalBitmaps[i].getConfig(), true); 

  }

Comment: Just use it on initialization (copy the original bitmap), and make sure that you're updating the bitmaps array when you're using your filter. You're probably not saving the filtered bitmap at the old one position.

Comment: Ok will try that now, is there any other modification to the code apart from your answer?

Comment: I updated my answer, try with just the modified code I posted.

Comment: Hold on I am trying something.

Comment: I believe (from the JavaDoc) you are using the copy method the wrong way around guys. "Tries to make a new bitmap based [...] on this bitmap,[...] and then copying this bitmap's pixels into the new bitmap." Thus you'd have to call the method on the original images and pass along their config and ASSIGN the return value. So you'd need:
`_filterImageView[i] = _originalBitmaps[i].copy(_originalBitmaps[i].getConfig(), true);`

Comment: Yes, i didn't review the copy function he wrote, i should have. It should work now !

Comment: Where ? Did you used the "copy" line from patrick comments ? It should work, but add the log to your question so we can see where it crashes.

Comment: SORRY GUYS. MY BAD. IT WORKSSSSS =)

Comment: I was close to figuring it out hehe but just didnt use the copy function right.